# jquery image hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I want to make a hover effect using jquery. Opacity and a simple zoom icon.

This is what i´ve got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.mpost-t1-img').animate ({
    opacity: 1
});

$('.mpost-t1-img').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.5});
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1});

});
```

This works for the opacity. But how can I add the image to the hover state? Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by "image to the hover state" ??

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to change the image `src` on hover and change it back on mouseout?

Comment: @dku.rajkumar I want to add a image over the default image when i mouseover.

Comment: check my answer.. hope that will help you.

Comment: With "a simple zoom icon" do you mean a small magnifier icon above the hovered image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Update)
I've read in other comments that you want overlay. For basic overlay you don't need any JS, but pure CSS. Below is example.

CSS:

```
.gallery a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 168px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 2px;
}

.gallery a img {
    max-width: 168px;
    max-height: 128px;
}

.gallery a .overlay {
    background-image: url('http://www.urbanoid.hu/wp/empire/wp-content/themes/empire/images/image_overlay.png'); 
    background-position: center center;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 168px; 
    height: 128px;
}

.gallery a:hover .overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img1" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img2" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7Mqer/2/

Then if you want animation, you can add some JS. Below is example.

Changes in CSS:

```
.gallery a .overlay {
    /*display: none;*/
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.gallery a .overlay').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1.0});        
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0});
    }
);
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7Mqer/1/

Comment: That only works for the opacity! i need to change the image also on while hover.

Comment: Strange, on jsfiddle it´s working but in my website it is not. Opacity is working but the image does not show.

Comment: shouldnt it work nice with the addClass method? it shloud be less code in javascript.

Comment: You can switch css class, but then image must be set as background. If you do so, you can also use `:hover` pseudo class instead of changin class via JS. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/a7fez/3/

Comment: I've read in other comment that you want overlay like in http://themeforest.net/item/empire-elegant-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/1199025, so I've modified my answer.

Comment: thank you. I guess that is the best way. works perfect to me.

Answer (score 0):

change the attribute `src` , something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mpost-t1-img').animate ({
     opacity: 1
  });

  $('.mpost-t1-img').hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.5},1000,'linear');
    }, function(){
       $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},1000,'linear');
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn´t work here. Do I need to change anything in the html for that attribute to work? I´ve also tried the addClass and then css put the zoom image I want to show when hovering. But doesnt work also. Don´y know what i´m doing wrong here.

Comment: I just need this effect (http://themeforest.net/item/empire-elegant-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/1199025) you can see it when you hover an image. I have the opacity working, but i also would like to see that zoom image.

Comment: Sorry I don´t think the link I gave you was working like it should. you must click on gallery menu link. And the effect i need is on those small thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.It might be useful.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.mpost-t1-img').animate ({
        opacity: 1
    });

    $('.mpost-t1-img').hover(function() {
        $(this).attr({'src':'img.jpg'});
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.5});
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr({'src':'img2.jpg'});
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1});
    });


});
```

Let me know if any query.

Thanks.

Comment: does not work here! dont know what i´m doing wrong here. the image is inside a span with 150px x and y. opacity works nice, but that image just won´t show up when I mouseover the default image.

Comment: this is what I need (http://themeforest.net/item/empire-elegant-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/1199025) then if you click on gallery menu link. The effect I need is in those thumnail. Just a simple zoom icon.

Answer (score 0):

change the src attribute too

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.mpost-t1-img').animate ({
    opacity: 1
});

$('.mpost-t1-img').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.5});
        $(this).attr('src',original src');
    }, 
        function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1});
        $(this).attr('src',src to change');
    }
);
```

});

[visit it](http://jsfiddle.net/KnH8A/1/)